# SQL delete where clause

Tags: mysql

I have a delete statement which is used to delete 20000 records in the database. Each row in these 20000 records satisfies two conditions: id=x and new_tracking_number=y. The details are as follows:

```
DELETE FROM tracking_number_pool WHERE (
    (id=88 AND new_tracking_number='LPT99') OR 
    (id=87 AND new_tracking_number='LPT98') OR 
    (id=86 AND new_tracking_number='LPT97') OR 
    (id=85 AND new_tracking_number='LPT96') OR 
    (id=84 AND new_tracking_number='LPT95') OR 
    ...
    (id=72 AND new_tracking_number='LPT83') 
);
```

When I ran the delete statement above in production environment, it took very long to complete the execution. I wonder how I can improve the efficiency of this delete operation.

Comment: MySQL is very poor at optimizing `OR` conditions, this probably isn't able to use the index.

Comment: If the `id` and `new_tracking_number` are in continuous range then you could use `IN RANGE` construct. Not entirely sure that it'd improve efficiency though.

Comment: @Ashutosh But he wants to pair each id with a specific `new_tracking_number`, so he can't use ranges.

Comment: The condition is checked for every id and tracking number.
this results in more no of iteration

if a range is specified, the iterations will be less and might increase the performance

Comment: @SanjeevS How would you use a range for this? If you say `id BETWEEN 78319988 AND 78319972 AND new_tracking_number BETWEEN 'LPT0000001699999' AND 'LPT0000001699983'` you'll get combinations that aren't in the desired list.

Comment: @Barmar wouldn't a composite index help?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
DELETE FROM 
tracking_number_pool
WHERE (id, new_tracking_number) in (
  (78319988, 'LPT0000001699999'),
  (78319986, 'LPT0000001699997'),
  ..
)
```

Comment: I tried `EXPLAIN` on a query like this in my DB, it didn't use any indexes.

Comment: Any reasons why this would be more efficient?